# Where are dotnet tools stored by default?

Tags: .net-core

I am using Windows 10 and and dotnet 2.2. When I install a tool like this:

```
dotnet tool install -g mydotnet-tool
```

Where does dotnet put this tool? I know you can specify the path on installing a tool but I am looking for the default global dotnet tool path.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools#install-a-global-tool), the default global installation paths are:

- Windows - `%USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\tools`
- Linux/macOS - `$HOME/.dotnet/tools`

In Windows, this means the full path will be something like:

```
C:\Users\[User]\.dotnet\tools
```

Comment: Do you know why .net global tool are installed under user profile instead of somewhere global?

Comment: @MichaelSync global tools are still only global to the current user, not the whole machine. Local tools are local to specific directories.

Comment: I think that description is confusing. `Local` means you can only run the executable from the directory it's in or given the fully qualified path, but `Global` just means the path to the directory is added to your user's PATH so you can type `sqlpackage` anywhere and it will find it. Really `Global` is a misnomer and a perfect example of how difficult it is to name things properly.

Answer (score 12):

**Global Tools**

According to the docs, the default global installation paths are:

- Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\tools`
- Linux/macOS: `$HOME/.dotnet/tools`

In Windows, this means the full path will be something like:

```
C:\Users\[User]\.dotnet\tools
```

**Local Tools**

Local tools are stored in the [global NuGet package folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders).

- Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages`
- Mac/Linux: `~/.nuget/packages`

In Windows, this means the full path will be something like:

```
C:\Users\[User]\.nuget\packages
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach it is to have `dotnet` show where a given package is:

`dotnet new details TemplateNameHere --diagnostics`

Currently, the first line of the output shows Global Settings Location.